# Runtime error 3078 "Cannot find input table" when using subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I'm having trouble running this (admittedly clunky) SQL query in a VBA Script via DAO. It keeps giving me runtime error 3078, saying that "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'SELECT Hist2.DateM ... GROUP BY Hist2.DateM'"

When I run the query in Access, it works as intended. Am I missing something obvious? Is there something about the way I'm calling the SQL statement from Excel that might be causing this?

```
SELECT Hist.DateM, Sum(Hist.Oil) AS SumOfOil, Sum(Hist.Gas) AS SumOfGas, Sum(Hist.GasSold) AS SumOfGasSold, Sum(Hist.Water) AS SumOfWater, Sum(Hist.InjWater) AS SumOfInjWater, Sum(Hist.DspdWater) AS SumOfDspdWater, OilCount.OilCount AS PrdCount, InjCount.InjCount
FROM ((MoPrdData AS Hist INNER JOIN WellMaster AS Loc ON Hist.WellID = Loc.LocationID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT Hist2.DateM, Count(Hist2.Oil) AS OilCount 
    FROM MoPrdData Hist2 INNER JOIN WellMaster Loc2 ON Hist2.WellID = Loc2.LocationId 
    WHERE Loc2.LeaseID = "26.00726" AND Hist2.Oil <> 0
    GROUP BY Hist2.DateM ) AS OilCount ON Hist.DateM = OilCount.DateM) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT Hist3.DateM, Count(Hist3.InjWater) AS InjCount
    FROM MoPrdData Hist3 INNER JOIN WellMaster Loc3 ON Hist3.WellID = Loc3.LocationId 
    WHERE Loc3.LeaseID = "26.00726" AND Hist3.InjWater <> 0
    GROUP BY Hist3.DateM )  AS InjCount ON Hist.DateM = InjCount.DateM
WHERE Loc.LeaseID="26.00726"
GROUP BY Hist.DateM, OilCount.OilCount, InjCount.InjCount;
```

Edit: Probably should include the VBA I'm using, since that might be the issue.

```
Sub GrabLeaseData()
'Clear the data
Sheets("PDE").Range("D2:XFD1048576").Clear

'Create links to data sources
Dim PWO As DAO.Database
Set PWO = Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("PrdAcct", dbDriverNoPrompt, True, "ODBC;DSN=PrdAcct;DATABASE=PrdAcct")

Dim strSQL As String
Dim LeaseID As String
LeaseID = "26.00726" 'TODO: Parameterize this 

'Grab data
Dim Data As DAO.Recordset
strSQL =    "SELECT Hist.DateM, Sum(Hist.Oil) AS SumOfOil, Sum(Hist.Gas) AS SumOfGas, Sum(Hist.GasSold) AS SumOfGasSold, Sum(Hist.Water) AS SumOfWater, Sum(Hist.InjWater) AS SumOfInjWater, Sum(Hist.DspdWater) AS SumOfDspdWater, OilCount.OilCount AS PrdCount, InjCount.InjCount" & _
            "FROM ((MoPrdData AS Hist INNER JOIN WellMaster AS Loc ON Hist.WellID = Loc.LocationID) " & _
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN ( " & _
                "SELECT Hist2.DateM, Count(Hist2.Oil) AS OilCount " & _
                "FROM MoPrdData Hist2 INNER JOIN WellMaster Loc2 ON Hist2.WellID = Loc2.LocationId " & _
                "WHERE Loc2.LeaseID = """ & LeaseID & """ AND Hist2.Oil <> 0 " & _
                "GROUP BY Hist2.DateM ) AS OilCount ON Hist.DateM = OilCount.DateM) " & _
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN ( " & _
                "SELECT Hist3.DateM, Count(Hist3.InjWater) AS InjCount " & _
                "FROM MoPrdData Hist3 INNER JOIN WellMaster Loc3 ON Hist3.WellID = Loc3.LocationId " & _
                "WHERE Loc3.LeaseID = """ & LeaseID & """ AND Hist3.InjWater <> 0 " & _
                "GROUP BY Hist3.DateM )  AS InjCount ON Hist.DateM = InjCount.DateM " & _
            "WHERE Loc.LeaseID= """ & LeaseID & """ " & _
            "GROUP BY Hist.DateM, OilCount.OilCount, InjCount.InjCount; "

Debug.Print strSQL
Set Data = PWO.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

'Process results 
End Sub
```

Comment: If it works in A but not B then as you say its most likely the issue is how you call it in B. So how do you call it in B?

Comment: My theory is if you're providing this to DAO then the double quotes will probably throw it off.  You can add a watch to the query line to see what is actually being sent to populate your recordset.  I usually use single quotes around the value, or for example ""26.00726""

Comment: @AlexK. - Included VBA. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @JimmySmith I tried single quotes earlier, still throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a simple debugging issue.**

Cut and paste the query into SSMS.  Create a variable for @LeaseId.  Declare and set the variable.
Once you get it working in SSMS, modify it to work in VBA.

I will tell you right now, I did see some brackets that I did not like.

Also, you could turn this into a **stored procedure** and just past the LeaseId as a parameter.  Less SQL coding on the VBA side and it will be compiled.

**Issues:**

1 - You are grouping by OilCount.OCVar by not listing it at the top. Why?

2 - OilCount.OilCount AS PrdCount should be SUM(OilCount.OilCount) AS PrdCount if I understand what you are trying to do.

When grouping, the column has to be part of the group by clause or some aggregate function like sum, min, max, etc.

**USER TYPO** - Fixed by using OilCount in group by.

Try this and let me know how you make out.

```
-- Add sample lease number
DECLARE @LeaseID VARCHAR(12) = '12345678';

-- Try query
SELECT 
    Hist.DateM,
    OilCount.OilCount AS PrdCount,
    InjCount.InjCount,
    Sum(Hist.Oil) AS SumOfOil, 
    Sum(Hist.Gas) AS SumOfGas, 
    Sum(Hist.GasSold) AS SumOfGasSold, 
    Sum(Hist.Water) AS SumOfWater, 
    Sum(Hist.InjWater) AS SumOfInjWater, 
    Sum(Hist.DspdWater) AS SumOfDspdWater

FROM 
    MoPrdData AS Hist 

INNER JOIN 
    WellMaster AS Loc ON Hist.WellID = Loc.LocationID

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ( SELECT Hist2.DateM, Count(Hist2.Oil) AS OilCount 
      FROM MoPrdData Hist2 
      INNER JOIN WellMaster Loc2 ON Hist2.WellID = Loc2.LocationId 
      WHERE Loc2.LeaseID = @LeaseID AND Hist2.Oil <> 0 
      GROUP BY Hist2.DateM 
    ) AS OilCount ON Hist.DateM = OilCount.DateM


LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ( SELECT Hist3.DateM, Count(Hist3.InjWater) AS InjCount 
      FROM MoPrdData Hist3 
      INNER JOIN WellMaster Loc3 ON Hist3.WellID = Loc3.LocationId
      WHERE Loc3.LeaseID = @LeaseID  AND Hist3.InjWater <> 0 
      GROUP BY Hist3.DateM 
    )  AS InjCount ON Hist.DateM = InjCount.DateM 

WHERE 
    Loc.LeaseID = @LeaseID 

GROUP BY 
    Hist.DateM, 
    OilCount.OilCount, 
    InjCount.InjCount
```

Comment: Sorry, OCVar is a typo. Should be OilCount.OilCount

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to SSMS. ODBC is the only option to query the DB I know of without jumping through some hoops with my IT Dept.

Comment: The client tools are a free download, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579, you can even install the express database if you want.  You just need access to the server.  There used to be MS Query but I think that product was weeded out in Office 10+.

Comment: I downloaded SSMS and the query above executed perfectly. Tried using the above as the SQL string in my VBA, and ran into the same issue as above. I think the problem lies in the fact that VBA is using the Jet database engine to parse the query. I'm going to look at maybe changing my connection string and seeing if that changes anything. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Change the LEFT OUTER JOIN AND INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN and JOIN.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx  See if that helps

Comment: Still no luck. I think I'm just going to execute the three queries separately and join them manually in Excel. It's a PITA, but I don't see any other option at this point.

Comment: When you install the client tools, did the import/export wizard install?  If so, select SQL Server as the source and Excel as the target.  Has to be an existing excel sheet.  This should run the query and dump the data from SQL to Excel.  Basically a SSIS package.  http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/202/simple-way-to-export-data-from-sql-server/